# find named entities from tokenized sentences in SPACY v2.0

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to do:

- Tokenize sentences from text
- Compute Named Entities for each word present in sentence

This is what I have done so far:

```
nlp = spacy.load('en')
sentence = "Germany and U.S.A are popular countries. I am going to gym tonight"
sentence = nlp(sentence)
tokenized_sentences = []
for sent in sentence.sents:
        tokenized_sentences.append(sent)
for s in tokenized_sentences:
        labels = [ent.label_ for ent in s.ents]
        entities = [ent.text for ent in s.ents]
```

Error:

```
    labels = [ent.label_ for ent in s.ents]
    AttributeError: 'spacy.tokens.span.Span' object has no attribute 'ents'
```

Is there any alternative way to find named entities of tokenized sentence?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you only have two entities - USA and Germany.

The simple version:

```
sentence = nlp("Germany and U.S.A are popular countries. I am going to gym tonight")    
for ent in sentence.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

What i think you are tying to do:

```
sentence = nlp("Germany and U.S.A are popular countries. I am going to gym tonight")
for sent in sentence.sents:
    tmp = nlp(str(sent))
    for ent in tmp.ents:
        print(ent.text, ent.label_)
```

Comment: One small improvement: Instead of `str(sent)`, it's cleaner to explicitly use `sent.text_`, which gives you the sentence text. Calling `str` on the object can easily lead to unwanted side-effects – for example, in Python 2, this will give you a byte string instead of a unicode string.

Comment: @InesMontani: it is `sent.text`

Answer (score 0):

`ents` works only with doc (`spacy.tokens.doc.Doc`), if you use `doc=nlp(text)`

sent is of type `spacy.tokens.span.Span` which has no `ents` method.

Convert it to text and use `nlp()` again.

```
print([(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in nlp(sent.text).ents])
```